# To have OnSelect event without having Select button in GridView in ASP.net 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, datagridview

I am developing Web application in asp.net 4.0.
I am using a datagrid to display data from database.
I dont want to enable the select button feature of gridview in .net 4.0
But I want to have onRowSelected kind of event to populate on click of a row in gridview.
Please help me to achieve this!

Comment: Its not very clear what you need to achieve here, could you give us more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add templatefield with custom select button, hide it with css and attach that button click on row click event in GridView's `RowDataBound` event handler:

```
.hidden
{
     display: none;
}

<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" >
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SelectButton" CommandName="Select" />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var selectButton = e.Row.FindControl("SelectButton") as Button;
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(selectButton, "");
    }
}
```